# coloring a row including cells in hidden columns

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365, vba

For my worksheet I have written a VBA code to hide some chosen columns. After hiding these columns I want to mark and color a row. After that I want to unhide the columns so that I get back to my original sheet but with the chosen row fully colored.

The VBA works totally fine. My problem is that when I chose a row (clicking on the number of the row) and color it, when I unhide the columns those cells of the row that were hidden in the columns are not colored.

Is there any chance to color the whole row even though some cells are hidden by the macro?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code as well for a better understanding

Comment: The coloration of the row happens manually. The code for hiding some columns is the following: `ActiveSheet.Columns("A:F").Hidden = True`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Would that be fine to color the row via VBA?

Comment: @Pierre44 - No the VBA does not have anything to do with the coloring directly. Let's say the VBA hides column A. The I manually color the first row (from column B on since A is now hidden). When I unhide column A via a 2nd VBA the cell in column A of the colored first row stays un-colored. I hope I could make it clear now.

Comment: One solution would be to add the color in your second code, by checking which rows are colored and color the cells that were previously hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Must say I was unable to recreate the problem. Using code like:

```
Rows(1).Interior.Color = vbBlue
```

Does color all cells in a row, even hidden ones. But however, in your case maybe use a piece of code to loop through all cells in a row up to the last used column and color each piece individually. Hopefully that will resolve your issue:

```
Sub SpecialLoop()
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
    Dim rw As Long

    rw = 5 'Obviously just type any row here or get the rownr. some other way    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rw, 1), Cells(rw, ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))

    For Each cl In rng
        If Intersect(cl, rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) Is Nothing Then 
            Range(cl.Address).Interior.Color = vbBlue
        Else
            Range(cl.Address).Interior.Color = vbBlue
        End if            
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Either way, I hope you can fix it now :)

Comment: This is much more elegant! Thank you @JvdV

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I solved the problem by simply adding the following code line and chose the cells that I wanted to color:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 1
```

Color can of course be modified.